# Left outer join + sub query with two opposite WHERE conditions

Tags: c#, mysql

In this query I want to get data from 3 tables in MySQL database to display it in Data Grid View in Win form c# my problem is I want to use sub query inside join query AND this sub query contains WHERE condition opposite the condition in main query.

**the following code is sub queries:**

```
    " (SELECT SUM(submittal.priceCurrentWorks) FROM "+database+ "submittal WHERE submittal.addToSummary = 'false') AS 'سعر الحالية'," +
    " (SELECT SUM(submittal.requiredQuantity) FROM " + database + "submittal WHERE submittal.addToSummary = 'false') AS 'الأعمال الحالية',"
```

**The following code is full query (sub and main):**

```
String LeftOuterQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT boq_table.itemNum AS 'رقم البند', boq_table.descriptionOfWork AS 'وصف البند', boq_table.unit AS 'الوحدة', boq_table.contractualQuantity AS 'كمية العقد', boq_table.priceNum AS 'فئة العقد'," + 
" IFNULL(SUM(summary.priceLastWorks), 0) AS 'سعر السابقة' ," +
" IFNULL(SUM(summary.executedQuantLastSummary), 0) AS 'الأعمال السابقة'," +
" (SELECT SUM(submittal.priceCurrentWorks) FROM "+database+ "submittal WHERE submittal.addToSummary = 'false') AS 'سعر الحالية'," +
" (SELECT SUM(submittal.requiredQuantity) FROM " + database + "submittal WHERE submittal.addToSummary = 'false') AS 'الأعمال الحالية'," +
" IFNULL(summary.percentage,0) AS 'النسبة'," +
" IFNULL(SUM(submittal.requiredQuantity),0) +" +
" IFNULL(SUM(summary.executedQuantLastSummary), 0) AS 'إجمالي الأعمال'," +
" IFNULL(SUM(summary.priceLastWorks), 0) +" +
" IFNULL(SUM(submittal.priceCurrentWorks), 0) AS 'إجمالي السعر'" +
" FROM " + database + "boq_table" +
" LEFT OUTER JOIN " + database + "summary ON " + database + "boq_table.itemNum = " + database + "summary.itemNum" +
" LEFT OUTER JOIN " + database + "submittal ON " + database + "boq_table.itemNum = " + database + "submittal.itemNum" +
" WHERE summary.summaryNumber = '"+lastSummaryNumber+ "' AND submittal.addToSummary = 'true'" +
" GROUP BY boq_table.itemNum"+ 
" ORDER BY boq_table.itemNum ";
```

The full query return the result that just achieve Where condition in full/main query which it

```
" WHERE summary.summaryNumber = '"+lastSummaryNumber+ "' AND submittal.addToSummary = 'true'"
```

and ignore Where condition in sub queries.

I need to display data that achieve `addToSummary = 'false'` in sub query
**AND** achieve `addToSummary = 'true'` in full/main query **at the same time.**

Comment: What you're wanting assistance with, exactly, is not clear. Can you improve your post by asking a specific question?

Comment: @colbybhearn thanks for your replay, I updated my post

Comment: Let me know if I can help you more, or please accept my answer if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may just need to adjust your subquery by removing 
`WHERE submittal.addToSummary = 'false'`

I don't see another option and here's why: The outer query's `WHERE` clause will be evaluated first. This means any rows returned must have `submittal.addToSummary` equal to **'true'**. Your subquery is evaluated after that, so (if I understand your schema) the subqueries are looking for `submittal.addToSummary` equal to **'false'** where there are only `submittal.addToSummary` equal to **'true'** values, due to the outer query's `WHERE` clause.